# How can i install the netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

I have installed the jdk9 but iam not able to install the netbeans on my laptop. Once i open the setup of netbeans then it says that "jdk not found and install it". Please give me your suggestions.

My notebook configurations are: Windows 10 8GB RAM HP pavilion series

Iam trying to install both new and old version of the netbeans  and the error message i get every time is:
"Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer"      and then it gives the link for downloading jdk
And i have checked in command prompt and it shows the proper and correct message of jdk9 successfull installation.

Comment: how you checked in command prompt installation of jdk? have you typed `javac -version`?

Comment: Netbeans does not support Java 9, yet.

Comment: Yess i have typed that command and it displays the java version 9.

Comment: try to execute of Neatbeans installation by hand like that: `netbeans8.02.exe --javahome "C:/program files/java/jdk9.01"`. Pass your own env variables

Answer (score 2):

I have read something about NetBeans latest version here: https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/index.html

and
https://netbeans.org/features/index.html

I saw something:

- NetBeans IDE 8.2 provides out-of-the-box code analyzers and **editors for working with the latest Java 8 technologies--Java SE 8**, Java SE Embedded 8, and Java ME Embedded 8

- And **NetBeans IDE is the official IDE for Java 8**

Maybe you shouldn't try the latest version of Java, you should try to install Java 8 with Netbeans here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

So, finally, if my opinion isn't right, maybe you should check java Home path in window env variables by command prompt: java -version

Comment: you are talking about in what version of java you can work within netbeans, but question about jdk version to launch netbeans app.

Comment: Aha, Oke, fine. Your question is how to Netbeans can launches app using  jdk 9. You can try: https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/using-apache-netbeans-incubating-jdk-9 and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/2017/10/19/Test+Netbeans+with+JDK9+on+Windows+10+step+by+step

Answer (score 1):

To use Neatbeans with jdk9 use nightly build, the full definition here: [netbeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support)